# Using the select on jquery tabs?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Hi I want to perform a task when I click a **specific** tab, let's say #tab-2. how is that done? I don't understand the documentation on the jquery site.

I know how it's done on all tabs but not just one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this, just check the tab ID:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
   select: function(event, ui) {
     if(ui.tab.href == "#tab-2") { // or ui.panel.id == "tab-2"
       //do something...
     }
   }
});
```

[You can see what all elements are available on the passed `ui` argument here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/), `ui.tab` is the selected tab link (the `<a>`), `ui.panel` is the selected tab itself (the `<div>`).

Answer (score 1):

like this:

```
$("#tab-2").click(function() {
 //do something
});
```

?

Comment: I believe he means clicking the **tab**, as in the `<a href="#tab-2">`, not the contents on the tab, this wouldn't do that.

Comment: Oh, sorry - didn't ready the question properly :) Just saw "#tab" and "select" and assumed he didn't understand selectors properly.